# using curl to receive result from .sh

Tags: linux, bash, curl, apache2

I am trying to get the results (CPU Temperature remote machine) from a .sh file using curl, Instead I receive the code from the .sh.

my current code
curl -s http://192.168.1.5/cgi-bin/temp.sh

instead of returning the temp it returns the .sh file code

I am running Apache2, and if I place the sh in a index.php file, I can grep the output, but that seems like a step too much.

Thanks for any advice.

Tried changing file to .cgi instead.  Same results

Comment: if php is already working, you could just add a `temp.sh.php` file containing ```<?php passthru("./temp.sh");``` and curl the php file :P

Answer (score 0):

I found changing my `curl` command to the following resolved the issue:

```
curl -s http://192.168.1.5/cgi-bin/temp.sh | sh
```

I just pipe my `curl` command to `sh` to return the result.